# Return text input into react component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs

How I can achieve the similar functionality in React? The following angular code is from w3schools.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    Name: <input ng-model="firstname">
    <h1>{{firstname}}</h1>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstname = "John";
    $scope.lastname = "Doe";    
});
</script>

<p>Change the name inside the input field, and the model data will change automatically, and therefore also the header will change its value.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my code for the login page in react.I want to Modify this to reflect the User's name as they type. ie. if I type "Tyson" in the "name" field, I want the title to update in real time to "Hello Tyson".

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import withStyles from 'isomorphic-style-loader/lib/withStyles';
import s from './Login.css';

class Login extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  };
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      title: props.title,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={s.root}>
        <div className={s.container}>
          <h1>
            {this.state.title}
          </h1>
          <p className={s.lead}>Log in with your Name</p>
          <form onSubmit={e => e.preventDefault()}>
            <div className={s.formGroup}>
              <label className={s.label} htmlFor="name">
                Name
              </label>
              <input
                className={s.input}
                id="name"
                type="text"
                name="name"
                autoFocus // eslint-disable-line jsx-a11y/no-autofocus
              />
            </div>
            <div className={s.formGroup}>
              <label className={s.label} htmlFor="password">
                Password:
              </label>
              <input
                className={s.input}
                id="password"
                type="password"
                name="password"
              />
            </div>
            <div className={s.formGroup}>
              <button className={s.button}>Log in</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(s)(Login);
```

Comment: You don't need 2-way binding.

Comment: Look at the docs for "Controlled Components https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html

Answer (score 0):

Could you post your other component? You pass down a title via props, but don't provide this component. I can only guess what you are trying to do.
I don't see why you would need "title" as an attribute, given that it's always "Hello, {name}".

Login Component:

```
class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "",
      password: ""
    };
  }

  changeHandler = (value, {target: {name, type}}) => {
    this.setState({[name]: value}, () => {
        console.log("Your new state is:", this.state)});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={s.root}>
        <div className={s.container}>
          <h1>
            Hello, {this.state.name}
          </h1>
          <p className={s.lead}>Log in with your Name</p>
          <form onSubmit={e => e.preventDefault()}>
            <div className={s.formGroup}>
              <label className={s.label} htmlFor="name">
                Name
              </label>
              <input
                className={s.input}
                id="name"
                type="text"
                name="name"
                value={this.state.name}
                autoFocus // eslint-disable-line jsx-a11y/no-autofocus
                onChange={this.changeHandler}
              />
            </div>
            <div className={s.formGroup}>
              <label className={s.label} htmlFor="password">
                Password:
              </label>
              <input
                className={s.input}
                id="password"
                type="password"
                name="password"
                value={this.state.password}
                onChange={this.changeHandler}
              />
            </div>
            <div className={s.formGroup}>
              <button className={s.button}>Log in</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Is this what you want to do?